# Sliding with jQuery - animate() method

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, jquery-animate, css-animations

I am currently using the following code to (at least visually) replace the contents of a div, whose id is 'box3' (by hiding the current content and showing the new content) but by making the new content slide into appearance (the old content is just hidden without sliding).

```
var tabIndex = 1;

function nextButtonClick() {
    $("#box3").hide();
    $(".tab" + tabIndex).hide();
    $(".tab" + (tabIndex + 1)).show();
    $("#box3").animate({ width: 'toggle' }); 
    tabIndex++;
}
```

The problem is that this method makes the new content slide from left to right, whereas I want to slide right to left. I have tried looking around for how to change the slide direction, but nothing seems to work; it normally just makes all content disappear, leaving 'box3# visually empty.

(I am using this code as regular Javascript by the way; it is not within the 'ready' function.)

Can anyone suggest anything? Thanks, Conor.

Comment: It will be great if you can share your code using jsfiddle so that one can provide you exact solution.

Comment: Depending on your `css` you could just `float` it `right`. Please show us your full code

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/92n8z/ - I have never used jfiddle before, so I don't know how much code you expect.

Comment: @ConorW As much code as is applicable to reproduce the issue